# How to make PhoneGap Build app supporting more languages in Windows Marketplace?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, marketplace

I have managed to publish my first PhoneGap Build app to [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en) and [Windows Marketplace](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store).

When preparing an application for publication in Google Play I could provide description and other details in as many languages as I wanted, directly from Google Play Developer Console. However, I can't find anything similar in Windows Phone Dev Center.

In "*Upload and describe your package*" section and in "*Package's Store listing info*" group I can see:

> A package can contain multiple languages. Select a language to add Store listing info specific for that language

However, listbox below contains only one entry (`English`) and above, in "*Package details detected from file*" group, I can clearly see `Language(s)`: `EnglishNorthAmerica`. I've browsed my `config.xml` file, used in PhoneGap Build to build my `app.xap` file, but there is no language setting inside it.

What should I add to `config.xml` or what should I do in general, to be able to select more languages in "*Package's Store listing info*" group and to be able to provide app description in other languages?

Comment: Curse-you, ugly close-voter! :> Stand up! Be a man! Speak your reasons! :>

Answer (score 0):

According to [official PGB support](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how-to-make-phonegap-build-app-supporting-more-languages-in-windows-marketplace#reply_15822910) you need to add [this piece](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/1#issuecomment-51095069) of config-file code to your configuration:

```
<gap:config-file platform="winphone" parent="/Deployment" mode="replace">
    <Languages xmlns="">
        <Language code="en-GB"/>
        <Language code="pl-PL"/>
    </Languages>
    <DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="en-GB" />
</gap:config-file>
```

to your `config.xml` file and rebuild application to enable other languages in Windows Marketplace.

Things, you should note or consider:

1. Changing (or adding new) languages for your `.xap` file will invalidate all graphics and text added previously and you'll have to provide them again after this change, before publishing an update.
2. On contrary to Android, you are *required* to provide screenshots and descriptions of your app in *all* languages it support (it was optional in case of publishing app to Google Play). Failing to do so will prevent you from publishing an update of your application.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202918%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you'll find a complete list of culture and language codes supported by newest WP applications and [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_config_file_element.md.html#Config%20File%20Elements) a detailed information about config file elements, for those unfamiliar with them.